Tim the Anthropomorphic Bull Thought experiment
Let's consider Tim.
Tim is born on 1st September 1990. Tim goes to elementary school at six. Tim reads Harry Pottter at 12. Tim goes to his prom at 16.
Based on these sampling of events... how do we know that:

Tim is a healthy normal boy.
Tim is an anthropomorphized bull who, after high school graduation, will revert to his original form and live the rest of his existence as a full-fledged animal?

Predicate 1 and 2 both equally describe Tim well, but they are mutually contadictory: they can't both be true.
What gives?

@KristianBerry Yes. But the choice of predicates make it abtruse and hard to understand. This story is a lot more memorable, don't you think?!

@KristianBerry I don't know what the abstract template for both the grue-emerald one and my transformation is, but they both instantiate that same template separately.

@KristianBerry If this is about indices over possible worlds, then I discovered the pothead riddle of induction. Thank you.

I thought I had woken up this morning, but maybe... I'm still dreaming? :-)
